# What is the image of point $(3,4)$ after a translation $4$ units left, reflection across the $x$-axis, and translation $2$ units down?

Tags: geometry, reflection

> Point $a$ has coordinates $(3,4)$ After a translation $4$ units left, a reflection across the $x$ axis, and a translation $2$ units down, what are the coordinates of the image?

Answer (score 1):

First, after a translation 4 units left, the point would be at $(-1,4)$. And then we reflect it across the $x$ axis which would required us to switch the sign of $4$ therefore giving us the point $(-1,-4)$. Then we translate it 2 units down, leading to a final point of $(-1,-6)$.

You can learn more at https://www.brainfuse.com/jsp/alc/resource.jsp?s=gre&c=37810&cc=108830.